# Equating two operators in different bases

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose
$$[A]_B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & x\\
x & 7
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $A$ is some linear operator and $B$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. Also, suppose
$$[C]_D = \begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 0\\
0 & 5
\end{bmatrix}$$
is another linear operator and $D$ is another basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. For what values of $x$ is $A = C$?

How would I approach this problem?

Comment: So for what values of $x$ an operator is equal to a basis?!

Comment: Note that $[A]_D=M_{B\to D}[A]_BM_{D\to B}=M[A]_BM^{-1}=[C]_D$ so you want $[A]_B,[C]_D$ to be similar. Determinants of similar matrices are equal, which gives $x=\pm\sqrt{17}$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Yes it is a typo sorry. So this problem boils down into finding an appropriate $M$?

Comment: Yes. If you can verify that the two matrices are similar for $x=\pm\sqrt{17}$, you are done.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri How did you find $x$?

Comment: Determinants of similar matrices are equal..

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Wow so it is as simple as solving two determinants?

Comment: You still have to verify if the matrices are similar for $\pm\sqrt{17}$. In fact they are not, since they don't have the same set of eigenvalues. It looks like for no $x$ does $A=C$ hold true.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Assuming the eigenvalues were the same, would that suffice for calling the two matrices similar? If not, what would?

Comment: Yes. If eigenvalues are same, then they will be similar.

Comment: We have $\operatorname{Tr} A = 8$ and $\operatorname{Tr} B = 3$. Since the trace is a similarity invariant, if follows that $A$ and $B$ are never equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require $M[A]_BM^{-1}=[C]_D$ i.e. $[A]_B,[C]_D$ should be similar, where $M$ is the transformation matrix from basis $B\to D$. Since similar matrices have the same eigenvalues, you would need $-2,5$ to be the eigenvalues of $[A]_B$. Is there an $x$ which makes this possible?